Vifm command to display selected directory as :tree view in second pane
I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask questions about Vifm but I could not find any forum dedicated to it.
My goal is to separate Vifm in two panes, the second one showing the file information of the selected object of the first pane. If it is a directory, the second pane shows the inside of the directory in :tree mode, and if it is a file, it simply previews the file.
I was able to do it, but I do not like at all the way it was done, and I need help making a better version.
" repeated code for hjkl
nnoremap h :view!<CR>:view<CR>h:if filetype('.') != 'dir' | view! | else | :sync %c<CR>:winrun , tree | endif<CR>

Explanation:
:view!<CR>:view<CR> forces into view mode and then back out of it, as to reset my view each time.
h:if filetype('.') != 'dir' | view! presses 'h' and checks if the selected object is a directory, if not, it forces into view in order to preview the file.
else | :sync %c<CR>:winrun , tree if it's a directory, it will sync the second pane with the first one, as to have the selected directory become the one shown in the second pane (thanks to %c). winrun will then run ":tree" on the second pane as to show a tree view of the selected directory in the second pane.
Even though this works, it constantly displays the error message ":endif without :if" and also takes allot of time to load big directories, during which I cannot act.
My goal is to create a command that works constantly instead of when I press "hjkl", to remove the error message, and also to disable this whole command on a button press, or when I selected a folder that is too big. I have tried functions but was not able to create one, as Vifm is not very documented.
